# pdblp con.bdh() function pulling yield instead of price

Tags: python, pycharm, price, bloomberg, pdblp

I am interested in pulling the price of a bond using the con.bdh( ) function from the pdblp package. The below code keeps pulling the yield of the bond, instead of the price. Does anyone know how I can pull the price?

```py
import pdblp
con = pdblp.BCon
con = pdblp.BCon(debug=True, port=8194, timeout=5000)
con.start()
con.debug = False

con.bdh('AN479278 Corp','PX_LAST', '20190410', '20190410', longdata=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the override 'QuoteType=P'. This will change to price